# Read File in Listview in android

Tags: android, file, listview

I am trying to populate List view with my file data. What I have to do here is, I have to read file in one activity and pass this file data in another activity's List view. I have successfully pass this data in second activity's List view, but data are appearing in single row. Individual data are not appearing in individual row...Here is my code...

### FirstActivity.java

```
String myData = "";
String strLine;
String listName = "" ;
FileOutputStream fos;
FileInputStream fstream;
DataInputStream in;
String[] SavedFiles;
BufferedReader br;


public void readFile(String file) throws IOException
    {
        try
            {
                fstream = openFileInput(file);
                in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            while ((strLine=br.readLine()) != null)   
            {
                myData +=(strLine);
                mapList.add(strLine);

            }
            //FinalList.arrFriends = mapList;

            in.close();

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent in1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FinalList.class);
            in1.putStringArrayListExtra("Data", mapList);
            startActivity(in1);

        }
```

### SecondActivity.java

```
public class FinalList extends Activity{

    ListView lvFinal;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterFriends;
    public static ArrayList<String> arrFriends = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.final_list);

        lvFinal = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);
        Intent in = getIntent();
        arrFriends = in.getStringArrayListExtra("Data");
        adapterFriends = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.text, arrFriends);
        lvFinal.setAdapter(adapterFriends);
        adapterFriends.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

What am I missing?
Here is the image of output.

[image]

Comment: Can u post R.layout.text?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:textSize="20sp" >

</TextView>

Comment: Try to Use custom adapter & set its text in View.

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying exactly... can you explain?

Comment: Take a look on this link for listview Adapter.you are getting data in correct way but, your view is not correct. & view of listview is depend on  Adapter so improve your Adapter.http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-custom-listview-texts-and-images-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Check your file and make sure that each line followed by '\n', '\r', "\r\n"

Answer (score 0):

Finally done it...Read the file word by word...

```
public void readFile(String file) throws IOException
        {
            fstream = openFileInput(file);

            Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new DataInputStream(fstream));
            ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

            String theWord;     
            while (scanFile.hasNext()){
                theWord = scanFile.next();
                words.add(theWord);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), theWord, 1000).show();
            }


                Intent in1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FinalList.class);
                in1.putStringArrayListExtra("Data", words);
                startActivity(in1);

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's because you don't use the good style for display it.
Have you tried to use the ArrayAdapter this way:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, <your_list>)`
```

Comment: No, nothing happens.. And this is not the solution. I have applied my own style here.

Comment: I didn't understand your question then, sorry.

Comment: Can you see image which I updated here? I am getting output in single row, and not in individual row.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that but my solution work in way of getting all the data in a individual rows.
Maybe you could put your XML layout file too...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>